# Elasticsearch search like google

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to perform a search like google does in elasticsearch in mutiple fields using java. A very simple example of want I'm trying to do:
Having documents in the index with the phrases: "Toshiba I will buy", "Toshiba I don't wanna buy" and "Toshiba rock my world" with the search "Toshiba buy" returns all the 3 phrases.

How can I perform this in Java?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the split() method of the String class and the search in your database with each word separately.
For example-

```
String input = "Toshiba buy"; 
String words[] = input.split(" "); 
// this will split at every <space>. You could also use another de-limiter for exactly where you would like to split the sentence

for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
{
    //search in your database using words[i]
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I thought about this solution, but the problem is when I have the exact phrase ("prhase") in midle of the query: For example (the result is not related to the previouse example) <Rock "toshiba wold">. Another thing that concerns me are the wildcards that the query can have.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by exact phrase in the middle of the query. About wildcards, if the user enters the same wildcards as your database uses then it shouldn't pose a problem.

Comment: For example if you want to search in google for Hp Probook if you put between quotes than google will search for the prhase instead of each word... (more concrete example: documents with "hp laptop probook" and "hp probook laptop", searching for the prhase (between quotes) "hp probook" will give the last document)

Comment: Consider this-
        String input = jTextField1.getText();
        boolean check = input.matches(".*\".*\".*");
        if(check==true)
        {
            int start = input.indexOf('"')+1;
            int end = input.indexOf('"', start+1);
            String phrase = input.substring(start,end);
            //handle the string phrase i.e. the part in the quotes
        }
        
        else
        {
            //handle the case where the user did not enter quotes
        }

Comment: Sorry I'm unable to format the code in stack overflow.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel, I think you're missing he is using elasticsearch

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about the OSS elasticsearch.